# OperationalError at /result unable to open database file

Tags: python, django, database

I have this error for 2 days now I triyed everything in the other topics nothings works for me. The code of the app was written in linux, but i got the folder and connected it to my project as an app, in this project there is 3 apps that are connecting good to the database, only this one gives an error unable to open data base. I'm using Windows on Localhost, a friend triyed on windows and it's working for him, only for me not working.

Note : When I go to localhost:8000/admin I can see the model created on the database.
PLEASE HELP!

Django Version: 2.2.3
I have tryied to give permissions of the folder on it's proprieties to read and write, tryied to change path of DIR, I switched from sqlite3 to postgres, made full path in database and not full one, triyed all the recommandations on topics but still shows the error

Settings. py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'devee',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'thepasswordichoosed',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
 }
```

Environment:

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/result

Django Version: 2.2.3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'dashboard',
 'account',
 'analyse']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:  


File "C:\Users\I500913\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\I500913\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\I500913\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\I500913\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py" in wrapped_view
  54.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\I500913\Desktop\Projets\final\analyse\views.py" in analyse_result
  22.     seo_score, report = scrapper(website)

File "C:\Users\I500913\Desktop\Projets\final\analyse\seo_scrapper.py" in scrapper
  411.     sbl = SafeBrowsingList(api_key)

File "C:\Users\I500913\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gglsbl\client.py" in __init__
  35.         self.storage = SqliteStorage(db_path, timeout=timeout)

File "C:\Users\I500913\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gglsbl\storage.py" in __init__
  73.         self.db = sqlite3.connect(db_path, timeout)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /result
Exception Value: unable to open database file
```

Comment: please show code for: 411.     sbl = SafeBrowsingList(api_key)

Comment: api_key = 'theapikeyofgoogle'
    sbl = SafeBrowsingList(api_key)
    bl = sbl.lookup_url(url)

Comment: Thanks HenryM It was the solution, I deleted the row refering to safebrowsingapi and it worked!! Thanks a lot